# how can concatenate two string columns in one column in spark python

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe

I want to concatenate two column in dataframe as one column here I want to merge nameFirst and nameLast as column called FULL Name

```
+---------+---------+--------+
| playerID|nameFirst|nameLast|
+---------+---------+--------+
|aardsda01|    David| Aardsma|
|aaronha01|     Hank|   Aaron|
|aaronto01|   Tommie|   Aaron|
| aasedo01|      Don|    Aase|
+---------+---------+--------+
```

I'm trying this code :

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT playerID,(nameFirst+nameLast) as full_name FROM Master")
```

but it returns

```
+---------+---------+
| playerID|full_name|
+---------+---------+
|aardsda01|     null|
|aaronha01|     null|
|aaronto01|     null|
| aasedo01|     null|
```

any help please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use *concat* function:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT playerID, concat(nameFirst, nameLast) as full_name FROM Master")
```